# Icon OS X Xcode 4.3

Tags: xcode, macos, icons

I have an icon 256x256 png that i've added to my Xcode project, it's also specfied in the plist and shows on the Target summary and when I archive, however when I distribute as an app the icon is missing, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if the App Icon is named in the specified format. Please refer the following link for the Specified Format and Sizes of App Icons in OS X.
  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/applehiguidelines/IconsImages/IconsImages.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I have it named correctly and it shows correctly in xcode, just not after I build and run or archive!